# folding let- declaration of Ocaml under Emacs gives "invalide search bound" error information

Tags: emacs, ocaml, folding, outline

Under Emacs, I am trying to fold ocaml source files in such a way that:

> each let-definition is folded into something like "let myfunction =
>   ..."

This should be a natural request for all ocaml programmes. I think the answer for Emacs should be the outline-minor-mode. But for whatever command related to outline-mode,  I got the same error info. from the minibuffer

```
invalide search bound(wrong side of point)
```

For info, I am under Tuareg major mode for ocaml editing.  I activate outline-minor-mode by

```
M-x outline-minor-mode
```

then, I try to hide sublevels by

```
M-x hide-sublevels
```

which gives me the above mentioned error info.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior (with an emacs config void of anything related to outline-mode). Have you configured outline mode, and how ?